# How to compaire parts of a string in an array of objects with other strings?

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects, string-comparison

I have an array of objects in javascript like:

```
var arr_objects= [
   {id: 1, authors: "person1||person2", edithors: "person1||person7"}, 
   {id: 2, authors: "person3", edithors: "person2"}, 
   {id: 3, authors: "person4||person5||person6", edithors: "person7||person6"}, 
   {id: 4, authors: "person7||person6", edithors: "person6"}
];
```

I want to check if any name in "authors" (person1, person2 etc.) occurs in the same object in "edithors". If thats the case - write a new key-value pair ("occurance") to the object containing the name of the author/editor.

The output should look like this:

```
var arr_objects= [
   {id: 1, authors: "person1||person2", edithors: "person1||person7", occurance: "person1"}, 
   {id: 2, authors: "person3", editors: "person2" }, 
   {id: 3, authors: "person4||person5||person6", edithors: "person7||person6", occurance: "person6"}, 
   {id: 4, authors: "person7||person6", edithors: "person6", occurance: "person6"}
];
```

I am new to programming and seem to be completely stuck.
I guess to achieve the output, I have to use regulair expressions on "authors" and "editors" to separate the values and compaire both strings with eachoter. Unfortunately am unable to use the regex and loop through the array while comparing the values.

I would be very thankful for any advice regarding my problem.

Comment: You can use String.split to convert authors / edithors to arrays, and then look for which elements the 2 arrays have in common: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution with some explanations

```
arr_objects.map(function(item)
{
   // split both authors and editors into an array
   let authors = item.authors.split('||'); 
   let editors = item.edithors.split('||'); 
   let occurance = [];
   // for each author, check if it also appears among editors
   for (a in authors)
   {
      if (editors.indexOf(authors[a])>=0)
      {
          //if yes, push it into occurrence buffer
          occurance.push(authors[a]);
      }

   } 
// join the array into a string
item.occurance = occurance.join('||'); 
return item;
})
```

Comment: Thank you Eriks, that works perfectly! You saved me with this one.

Answer (score 1):

```
arr_objects.forEach(obj => {
    const authors = obj.authors.split('||');
    const editors = obj.edithors.split('||');
    const matches = authors.filter(val => editors.includes(val));
    if (matches.length) {
        obj.occurrences = matches;
    }
});
```

---

1. Split the authors and editors into two arrays.
2. Find all the duplicates between the two arrays.
3. Assign the duplicates to your new object property `occurrences`.

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr_objects= [
{id: 1, authors: "person1||person2", edithors: "person1||person7"}, 
{id: 2, authors: "person3", edithors: "person2"}, 
{id: 3, authors: "person4||person5||person6", edithors: "person7||person6"}, 
{id: 4, authors: "person7||person6", edithors: "person6"}
];

function getOccurance(arr){
// clone
arr = [...arr]

arr = arr.map(a => {
    let authors = a.authors.split("||");
    let editors = a.edithors.split("||")
    let occurance = ""
    authors.forEach(auth => {
        editors.forEach(ed => {
            if(auth == ed) {
                if(occurance.length > 0){
                    occurance += "||" + auth;
                }else{
                    occurance += auth
                }
                
            }
        })
    })
    if(occurance.length > 0){
        a.occurance = occurance
    }
    return a
})
return arr
}
console.log(getOccurance(arr_objects))
```

Answer (score 0):

No need for regex, you can use `split` to get an array of persons out of the `person7||person6` string :

```js
const persons = `person7||person6`.split('||');
```

The opposite can be done with `join` :

```js
['person7', 'person6'].join('||'); //evaluates to person7||person6
```

Now all you have to do is loop through `arr_objects`, split authors and edithors, compute their intersection and put it in occurance :

```js
for(obj of arr_objects) {
  const authors = obj.authors.split('||');
  const editors = obj.edithors.split('||');
  const intersection = computeIntersection(authors, editors);
  if(intersection.length > 0) {
    obj.occurance = intersection.join('||')
  }
}
```

Now all that's left is implementing `computeIntersection` :

```js
function computeIntersection(array1, array2) {
  let intersection = [];
  let visited = new Set();
  for(e of array1) {
    visited.add(e);
  }
  for(e of array2) {
    if(visited.has(e)) {
      intersection.push(e);
    }
  }
  return intersection;
}
```